# Programmatically efficient method for associating a string with a control in Visual Studio 2010 with Winforms

Tags: c#, string, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tooltip

I'm trying to find an efficient tooltip method that involves injecting a string into a statusbar at the bottom of a form. I have two methods, `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` which I would like to use to uniformly show a string associated with any random user control I set it up for.

`mouseLeave` is easy:

```
    private void mouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
    }
```

But `mouseEnter` is much more difficult, because each control needs its own string. I can hardcode these into the program if need be, I just want it to work without needing a different method for each object.

One method I'm trying is shown below (neither commented line works, but merely shows my progress):

```
    private void mouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = pictureBoxLogo.GetAccessibilityObjectById(AccessibleDescription);
        //toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = sender.ToString();
    }
```

When using `GetAccessibilityObjectById`, I get the error message:

> Error  23  Cannot access protected member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetAccessibilityObjectById(int)' via a qualifier of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'; the qualifier must be of type '.MainForm' (or derived from it)   \formMain.cs   59  59

And when using the `sender.ToString();` method, I get an incoherent string of text in the status bar. This is simply not the right property to be using.

Is there one propery of all controls I can utilize, which I can then fetch from them and insert as string? If not, what's the best way to ASSIGN a string to them in any way that will allow me then to get it as a string in `mouseEnter`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about leveraging the `Tag` property of the `Control` class. So for example, in the designer set the `Tag` of a `TextBox` to "This is my tooltip." and then in the `mouseEnter` do this:

```
var c = sender as Control;
if (c == null) { return; }

toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Tag);
```

Comment: This works for me! I can't say I completely get the concept below it. But I can tell you do, and you've made my day. Thank you (will vote as best answer as soon as I'm able)!

Comment: @JWarner112, I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Tag` property to store user specific information about a control.  Nothing else will touch it.  Though I'm not sure it's the right place for a localization string key.

The way that the traditional Tooltip normally works is that you define the tooltip for each object on the tooltip itself.  Internally it has a dictionary that essentially maps like so:

```
control1 -> "control1's tooltip"
control2 -> "control2's tooltip"
control3 -> "control3's tooltip"
```

Comment: Yes! I saw and tried to use `Tag` using the `GetAccessibilityObjectById` method, but it gave me the same error as above.

Comment: Why on earth are you calling that function?

Comment: In your MouseEnter function you receive a reference to the control in question.  You can just execute `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ((Control)sender).Tag as string;`

Comment: because I'm new to C# and have very little idea what I'm doing; The difference between visual programs and scripted programs is still getting me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dictionary with the control name as a key?

```
var ControlDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

ControlDict.Add("txtName", "Your Name");

toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ControlDict[sender.ToString()];
```